# Pandas - Creating pivot of duplicates index column

Tags: pandas, pivot

I am trying to create a pivot of my Dataframe that has no numerical values and duplicates exist in the index column. Given below is how my data looks:

```
sale_id, product, sale_date
101, ABC, 2021-01-01
101, DEF, 2021-02-01
101, XYZ, 2021-03-01
101, KLM, 2021-01-04
```

Expect the below output:

```
    ABC, DEF, XYZ, KLM
101 2021-01-01, 2021-02-01, 2021-03-01, 2021-01-04
```

I tried the below

```
df.pivot(index='sale_id', columns='product', values='sale_date')
```

It threw the below error

```
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to create a pivot of my Dataframe that has no numerical values and duplicates exist in the index column.

For test duplicates use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
df1 = df[df.duplicated(['sale_id','product'], keep=False)]
print (df1)
```

For remove duplicates use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
(df.drop_duplicates(['sale_id','product'])
   .pivot(index='sale_id', columns='product', values='sale_date'))
```